# Matching on a mockito mock object in scala 2.10

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest, scala-2.10

I am trying to inject a mock object created using Mockito with ScalaTest into a Scala program that uses a match statement. The program works fine in production but when I inject my mock object to test it I get:

```scala
scala.MatchError: (Mock for FileSource, hashCode: 707784476,null) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

The line causing the error is:

```scala
inputSources.foldLeft((inputSources.head, None): (FileSource, Option[ServerBackedFile]))
                     ((opt: (FileSource, Option[ServerBackedFile]), src: FileSource) => opt._2 match {...
```

And the mock object is created as such:

```scala
val mockSource0 = mock[FileSource]
when(mockSource0.getNextFile).thenReturn(None)
```

The class I am mocking, FileSource, is defined as:

```scala
trait FileSource {
def getNextFile: Option[ServerBackedFile]

def deleteRemoteFile(sbFile: ServerBackedFile): Unit
def disconnect: Unit
def a: String
def host: String
def b: Boolean
```

Comment: can you put the whole block inputsources.foldLeft?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 I can update it with the full code when I am next at work.

Comment: @oluies I actually was using ScalaMock and switched over to Mockito because of ScalaMock's inability to mock classes with parameters and also a bug in ScalaMock which means that it is unable to mock classes that inherit from java.io.File

Comment: I managed to work around it by avoiding matching on the Mockito mock object at all. I extracted the components of the tuple before passing it to the match as I only actually needed to match on the non-mock part of the tuple. Still curious if you can actually match on a Mockito mock though...